# JavaFX: Platform.exit() when there is a dialog window

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

I have an JavaFX application where multiple windows can be simultaneously opened. Some of these windows are also capable of spawning "dialog" windows. At the same time, the application check for certain conditions in the background, and it could immediately call `Platform.exit()` to terminate the whole application.

I have created a mini sample that shows how this can occur.

```
public class test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final VBox root = new VBox();
        final Scene sc = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Platform.runLater is necessary because this start() must not be blocked
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            final Button button = new Button("Exit");
            button.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());

            Stage st = new Stage();
            st.setScene(new Scene(button));

            st.initOwner(primaryStage);
            st.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); // Just need window-level modality

            st.showAndWait(); // Shows the "dialog" window
        });
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The exception thrown when the button is clicked:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.isNestedLoopRunning(Application.java:544)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isNestedLoopRunning(QuantumToolkit.java:1139)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:585)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at test.lambda$0(test.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What can I do to ensure safe calling of `Platform.exit()`?

Comment: I think that this approach to stopping the app is wrong. you must realize a clean shutdown of all open windows (and of all threads that you have started).

Comment: @mrmcwolf actually no, this is [one of the recommanded way to stop a JavaFX application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

Comment: Well, I have to admit. Though calling `Platform.exit()` to exit the application is the recommended way, but the fact that this is called while I have a "dialog" window open is a good hint that the whole application isn't very well designed.

Comment: @Jai One of solution is to call `st.show();` instead of `st.showAndWait();` but I do not understand why currently, especially by reading the [method javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) where it is precised that this method could be called from any thread.

Comment: @Jai If you absolutely want to keep the `Stage#showAndWait()` method for any reason, you could first close the stage `st.close()` and then call the `Platform.exit()`. Something like that `button.setOnAction(e -> { st.close(); Platform.exit();});` before the `showAndWait()` call.

Comment: @Pagbo That works for the sample, but not for the actual setup. In the actual code, the `Platform.exit()` call isn't called by the "dialog" window. In the actual environment, let's say I have 3 main windows `A`, `B`, `C` open. In `A`, it opens up a dialog (with window-level modality). Meanwhile, another main window `C` calls `Platform.exit()`, and `C` wouldn't know that `A` is running and has a dialog open.

Comment: Do not use `Platform.exit()`. Make the logic for clear application shutdown by closing everything open. This is done by logging all dialogs into a manager who closes them when needed.

Comment: @Jai Is the `Application` class aware of the different stages you get ? If it is, you can override the `stop` method (inherited from Application) and closes all showing stages if any.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll see how I can refactor my project to handle this. Meanwhile I have also submitted a bug report. I think the API can handle this in a more graceful manner.